# Unable to change tab in UItabbarController, when navigate (Push) to this tabbarController from an another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

Before saying a thing, let me explain my hierarchy. Say, I have an initial navigation controller in which I have my first `SignInViewController`. From here, I want to go to my `UITabbarController`, by a button press. Please take have a look into the below image :

[image]

My `UITabbarController` `storyboard identifier` is this `tabbarControllerID`. So in my `SignInViewController` sing-in button action I try like this :

```
- (void)goToHomeViewController
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:mainStoryboard bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarControllerID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabbarController animated:YES];
}
```

Which actually bring me to the `UITabbarController`, but the problem is, I can't change any other tab there. It like freeze. I have tried with `tabbarController` `selected index` `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;`. But it's not working. What am I missing here?
Thanks a lot in advance. Have a good day.

**PS:** I have called `- (void)goToHomeViewController` like this :

```
- (void)addUserModelClassToCoreData
{
    NSString *givenPhoneNumberWithCountryCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.countryCode, self.phoneNumberTextField.text];
    NSString *givenPassword = self.typePasswordTextField.text;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL), ^{
        BlockWeakSelf weakSelf = self;
        SignInWithPhoneNumberViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

        UserModelClass *userModelClass = [[UserModelClass alloc] init];
        userModelClass = [RetrieveRequestToServerClass retrieveRequestToServerForUserModelForPhoneNumber:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", givenPhoneNumberWithCountryCode]];

        if ([userModelClass.user_password isEqualToString:givenPassword]) {
            //Add UserModel to CoreData
            strongSelf.coreDataManager = [[CoreDataManager alloc] init];
            UserModelClass *userModelCls = [[UserModelClass alloc] init];
            userModelCls = [strongSelf.coreDataManager retrieveUserModelFromUserModelClassCoreData];

            if (userModelCls.user_phone_number.length != 0) {
                [strongSelf.coreDataManager deleteFromUserModelClassCoreData];
            }
            [strongSelf.coreDataManager addToUserModelClassCoreDataForUserModel:userModelClass];
            [strongSelf goToHomeViewController];
        } else {
            ExecuteCodeOnMainThread(
                                    [strongSelf initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Wrong Password" withMessage:@"Your Password is not correct. Please try again."  withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];
                                    )
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *"It like freeze"* ... well, ***is it frozen?*** Or can you tap the Back button and navigate back to your `SignInViewController`? Do you see the `HomeVC` of the tab controller? If you tap the Tabs, do you see visual feedback on the tab itself, but the tab content doesn't change?

Comment: I can't select other tab in my `tabbarController` and default `back button` (back button with VC name) didn't work. :(

Comment: Another thing, I came to this `tabbarController` from that same `SignInVC` by another button using `segue`, just for testing. And it works nicely.

Comment: Do you properly see your `HomeVC`? If you rotate the device, does the screen update correctly? Do you have any buttons on your `HomeVC` that you could connect to an IBAction and see if it the app is "frozen" or not?

Comment: Rotation is currently off, and I actually don't have any controller in my UI. Let me check.

Comment: Yup, my controller in HomeVC is showing perfectly. Here, I think I want to mention one thing is that, my `- (void)goToHomeViewController` is calling from a background thread. And it takes to much time to land on `tabbarController` then usual. The thread code is added in my question.

Comment: OK - a tip: When asking a question, provide the full information up-front. So... why are you trying to execute that on a background thread? UI methods must be done on the main thread. If *"it takes to much time to land on tabbarController then usual"* then that's the ***first*** place to look. Once you've solved that, the rest of your initial question may be moot.

Comment: Holy moly! I have just added my `- (void)goToHomeViewController` in main thread and it's working perfectly. :)
So the problem was, **I need to call my navigation methods in main thread.**

Like this :   

ExecuteCodeOnMainThread(
                                    [strongSelf goToHomeViewController];
                                    )
And thanks a lot for your interest. Have a nice day. :)